# Coq simpl / unfold only once. (Replace part of goal with the result of one iteration of a function.)

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic, induction

I am an instructor at university for a class titled *Type Systems of Languages* and the professor used the following example for inductive proofs in Type Theory on the board last lecture:

> Suppose, that there are natural numbers defined inductively (for some reason he insists on calling them terms) and we have a *greater than* function defined recursively on them. We can proove that for every n it holds that (suc n > n).

I have the following Coq code prepared for implementing this in a class:

```ml
Inductive term : Set :=
  | zero
  | suc (t : term)
.

Fixpoint greaterThan (t t' : term) {struct t} : bool :=
  match t, t' with
   | zero, _ => false
   | suc t, zero => true
   | suc t, suc t' => t > t'
  end
where "t > t'" := (greaterThan t t').

Lemma successorIsGreater : forall t : term, suc t > t = true.
Proof.
  induction t.

  (* zero *)
  - simpl.
    reflexivity.

  (* suc t *)
  -
```

which takes me to the following goal:

```
1 subgoal
t : term
IHt : (suc t > t) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
(suc (suc t) > suc t) = true
```

I can solve this in multiple ways by rewriting, unfolding, and / or simplifying before it just turns into reflexivity, but what I would really like to do to make it cleaner is to apply one iteration of greaterThan, that would just turn `(suc (suc t) > suc t) = true` into `(suc t > t) = true`, and I could finish the proof with `exact IHt`.

Is there a way to ahieve this?

ps.: I know that I can `simpl in IHt` and then use `exact`, but it expands to the match expression which is much more verbose than what is neccessary here.

*Edit:* Thanks to `Théo Winterhalter`'s answer I realized that I could also use `exact` by itself, since the terms are convertible, but that wouldn't show the process too well to the students. (Side note: Both cases of the induction are solvable with `trivial` as well, but I don't think that they would learn too much from that either. :D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility is to use the `Arguments` vernacular to tell `simpl` not to reduce `greaterThan` to a match expression. Put `Arguments greaterThan: simpl nomatch.` somewhere after the definition of `greaterThan`. Then when you use `simpl` in the environment

```
1 subgoal
t : term
IHt : (suc t > t) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
(suc (suc t) > suc t) = true
```

you get

```
1 subgoal
t : term
IHt : (suc t > t) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
(suc t > t) = true
```

as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a way to do it right off the bat.
One usual way is to prove a lemma corresponding the computation rule by reflexivity:

```
Lemma greaterThan_suc_suc :
  forall n m,
    suc n > suc m = n > m.
Proof.
  intros. reflexivity.
Defined.
```

(I'm using defined so that it really unfolds to `eq_refl` and goes away if need be.)

There is also the possibility of doing a `change` to do a substitution manually.

```
change (suc (suc t) > suc t) with (suc t > t).
```

It will check for convertibility and replace one expression by the other in the goal.

You can automate this process a bit by writing a tactic that does the simplification.

```
Ltac red_greaterThan :=
  match goal with
  | |- context [ suc ?n > suc ?m ] =>
    change (suc n > suc m) with (n > m)
  | |- context [ suc ?n > zero ] =>
    change (suc n > zero) with true
  | |- context [ zero > ?n ] =>
    change (zero > n) with false
  end.

Lemma successorIsGreater : forall t : term, suc t > t = true.
Proof.
  induction t.

  (* zero *)
  - red_greaterThan. reflexivity.

  (* suc t *)
  - red_greaterThan. assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: Though it's not exactly what I was looking for (since they are convertible, I could use `exact` by itself as well, which doesn't show the procedure to the students), change still seems to be my best bet, so thank you very much for mentioning that possibility! I will mark your answer to be the accepted if no better one arrives.

Comment: I hope someone does. I'd be glad as well. I'll update my answer with something more.

Comment: Thank you for the updated content, I really appreciate it!
At last I've marked `SCappella`'s answer as accepted, as it seems better suited for what I was looking for (requires less explanation), but there are great things to keep in mind as possibilities as well!